# manipulation of columns of data with awk and if - else if statments

Tags: multiple-columns, data-manipulation

I have .txt files like following one, several lines:

```
018 1003 229 1842 1A1 493246.2 7689486.2
018 1003 229 1841 1A2 493233.6 7689535.4
018 1003 229 1840 1A1 493286.9 7689515.8
018 1003 229 1839 1A2 493274.7 7689562.9
```

I need to add an extra column where to put values with this condition

```
If 1A1 new value=(1003 + 1)
If 1A2 new value=(1003 - 1)
```

desired output

```
018 1003 229 1842 1A1 493246.2 7689486.2 1004
018 1003 229 1841 1A2 493233.6 7689535.4 1002
018 1003 229 1840 1A1 493286.9 7689515.8 1004
018 1003 229 1839 1A2 493274.7 7689562.9 1002
```

Please note that this is an example, column 2 here is 1003 but for other files can be 1010 or 1001 etc.

I am using

```
cat ${seq}_${n_rline}.s01 |awk '{if ($5="1A1")print $0, ($2 + 1);else if ($5="1A2")print $0, ($2 - 1)} '> test100.txt
```

The output I got is

```
018 1003 229 1842 1A1 493246.2 7689486.2 1004
018 1003 229 1841 1A1 493233.6 7689535.4 1004
018 1003 229 1840 1A1 493286.9 7689515.8 1004
018 1003 229 1839 1A1 493274.7 7689562.9 1004
018 1003 229 1838 1A1 493329.0 7689544.6 1004
```

So I am replacing all the 1A2 and therefore the last column has all 1004.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I find the right command (or at least what it is working)

```
cat input.txt | awk '{if($5 ~/1A1/) print $0, ($2 + 1); else if($5 ~/1A2/) print $0, ($2 - 1)}' > output.txt
```